# Configuring STS/eclipse to work fast with macbook pro

Tags: eclipse, performance, macos, spring-tool-suite

I don't have a deep understanding in all of the vm flags and options of the `config.ini` file that used to run eclipse. I have the default file for `STS` version `3.3.0.RELEASE`:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts.icns
```

I'm trying to optimise the configuration for a `MacBook Pro` with `2.7 GHz Inter Core i7` processor and memory `16GB 1600 MHz DDR3`.

Comment: What is wrong with the default configuration?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Very slow :/ I work on a maven project with 200-300 modules and eclipse stucks oftenly.

Comment: What does Activity Monitor say the time is spent on?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Sorry for my ignorance but where do I see the Activity Monitor?

Comment: Activity Monitor is an OS X program capable of telling you what a given program does. You need to find out if Eclipse is swapping or garbage collecting.  You can also use jvisualvm to check gc performance.

Comment: look at [Martin Lippert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901564/optimal-performance-tuning-sts-on-mac-os-x) to my version of this question. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I'd say you are thrashing memory.  To be sure of this, go to Preferences -> General.  And then check "Show heap size".  If you often see the heap status in red, then you are thrashing memory.

To fix this problem, bump up your `Xmx` to 1024m or even higher.