# Optimal Performance tuning STS on Mac OS X

Tags: spring-tool-suite

What are the optimal performance tuning settings to put in my sts.ini file to ensure STS runs well on my Mac?

I am looking to optimize **two machines**. One is a MacBook Pro with 16GB ram and a 6-core 2.6Gh i7 processor and the other is an 8GB dual-core processor 2.2Ghz.

I am looking to get a **faster overall speed** for STS. The thing that really slows me down is the change event handler process. When it starts running then everything slows down.

There are quite a few one-off guides around for optimal performance tuning of the Spring Tool Suite. Some are written for a Windows platform and some for an OS X platform. Since STS runs on the JVM I thought the optimal settings would **work in either environment**.

I haven't seen a well-done list of performance tuning options. It would be nice to see if the configuration should change **based off of system properties** such as RAM, processor, and number of cores.

Comment: I am still using the settings mentioned here quite successfully: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/104143-how-to-change-memory-and-other-jvm-settings-for-sts?p=564437#post564437.

Comment: but the performance issues that you see might actually be an issue that we should fix in the implementation of STS. We optimized some additional things in 3.6.1 recently, so if you haven't already, you should give this version a try. Otherwise, please report performance issues via https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and we can work in improving the code.

Comment: @MartinLippert thanks for the suggestion. I combined your settings with a few of them at [Philip Yurchuck's page](http://philip.yurchuk.com/software/optimal-jvm-settings-for-sts/) to get my current settings: [GitHub Gist with settings](https://gist.github.com/kentoj/a711d88b896bfd35d4a8)
.