# Optimal performance for STS on windows

Tags: spring-tool-suite

What are the optimal performance tuning settings to put in my sts.ini file to ensure STS runs well on windows?

My machine has 8GB of RAM and a 3.2 GHz Intel Xeon processor

Comment: Here is a related thread with good pointers in the comments:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901564/optimal-performance-tuning-sts-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you could start by watching your heap status

> Window > Preferences > General > [-] Show Heap status

Remove unnecessary plugin loaded on the stratup

> Window > preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown

Remove plugins you do not need (e.g. you could remove Mylyn Task UI, if you are not using Mylyn)

In STS.ini you could increase minimum Heap size, to minimize GC calls, and unlock experimental JVM options.

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions

-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```